# What's up with the scraper sites?

Tags: discussion

I've come across all kinds of sites that are just scraping SE sites and taking the info for themselves, usually with a crappy UI. The most recent I've come across is http://earthwithsun.com/, which seems to be scraping SU. Are we doing anything about them? Do we even care?